# Best practice for forwarding messages between typed actors in the C++ Actors Framework?

Tags: c++, c++-actor-framework

I'm trying to hand off some work from one typed actor to another. The CAF user manual indicates that this can be done using the `forward_to` method. That method looks like it is only available to actors that are explicitly of the `event_based_actor` type. However, `forward_to` appears to be a thin wrapper over the `forward_current_message` method, which is defined for all actors of the `local_actor` type. Therefore, I assume it's okay to call `forward_current_message` directly?

Also, in order to get message forwarding working with typed actors, I still had to return a response from the intermediate actor. That actor's response seems to be ignored which is good, but am I doing something wrong? Or is it really necessary to pay the (normally minimal) cost of constructing a response that won't be used?

Here's the some working sample code that demonstrates my attempt at message forwarding with typed actors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "caf/all.hpp"

using namespace caf;
using namespace std;

using a_type = typed_actor<replies_to<int>::with<bool>>;
using b_type = typed_actor<replies_to<int>::with<bool>>;

actor worker()
{
    return spawn(
        [](event_based_actor *self) -> behavior
        {
            return
            {
                [self](int index)
                {
                    aout(self) << "Worker: " << index << endl;
                    return index;
                }
            };
        });
}

b_type::behavior_type bBehavior(b_type::pointer self)
{
    return
    {
        [self](int value)
        {
            // Create blocking actor
            scoped_actor blockingActor;

            // Spawn pool workers and send each a message
            auto pool = actor_pool::make(value, worker, actor_pool::round_robin());
            for(int i = 0; i < value; ++i)
            {
                blockingActor->send(pool, i);
            }

            // Wait for completion
            vector<int> results;
            int i = 0;
            blockingActor->receive_for(i, value) (
                [&results](int value)
                {
                    results.push_back(value);
                });

            blockingActor->send_exit(pool, exit_reason::user_shutdown);
            self->quit();
            return (value == results.size());
        }
    };
}

class A : public a_type::base
{
protected:
    behavior_type make_behavior() override
    {
        return
        {
            [this](int value) -> bool
            {
                aout(this) << "Number of tasks: " << value << endl;
                b_type forwardDestination = spawn(bBehavior);
                auto castDestination = actor_cast<actor>(forwardDestination);
                this->forward_current_message(castDestination);
                this->quit();
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
};


void tester()
{
    a_type testeeActor = spawn<A>();
    scoped_actor self;
    self->sync_send(testeeActor, 5).await(
        [testeeActor, &self](bool success)
        {
            aout(self) << "All workers completed? " << (success ? "Yes!" : "No :(") << endl;
        });
}

int main()
{
    tester();
    await_all_actors_done();
    shutdown();
    cout << "Press Enter to continue" << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Therefore, I assume it's okay to call forward_current_message directly?

No, `forward_current_message` ist not part of the public API in CAF (and is thus not listed in [Doxygen](http://actor-framework.org/doc/classcaf_1_1local__actor.html)). This means the member function could be renamed, removed, or made `protected`/`private` at any time.

The best practice to forward messages to typed actors is `delegate`. This is a new feature (introduced with [0.14.1](https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/releases/tag/0.14.1)) and unfortunately is not mentioned in the manual [yet](https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/issues/335). The best "documentation" currently available is its use in the [unit test for typed actors](https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/blob/02bc07c89115a1d58214ff5e1e2f499d68c4dade/libcaf_core/test/typed_spawn.cpp#L217).

The short version is: `delegate` is an alternative to `send` that forwards the responsibility for a request. In a typed actor, you can return `delegated<T>` instead of `T` from a message handler to indicate that an other actor will respond with a `T` to the original sender.

In your case, class `A` would be implemented like this:

```
class A : public a_type::base
{
protected:
    behavior_type make_behavior() override {
        return {
            [this](int value) {
                aout(this) << "Number of tasks: " << value << endl;
                auto forwardDestination = spawn(bBehavior);
                this->quit();
                return delegate(forwardDestination, value);
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much more elegant - it eliminates the need for casting and for the creation of a default value. For anyone else coming across this, I'd like to clarify that the typed_actor template definition remains unchanged when using delegate, despite the change in the handler's return type.